# nativescript handling REST non-200 responses

Tags: javascript, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Using Nativescript-Vue to make http calls and I would like to gracefully handle 404's and 500's.  Here is the code I am using that will return a 404 with a appllication/json message:

```
const httpModule = require("tns-core-modules/http");

httpModule.request({
  url: productApi,
  method: "GET"
}).then((response) => {
  console.log("===> received response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
  let status = response.statusCode;
  console.log("===> received status: " + status);
  if (status === 200) {
    var obj = response.content.toJSON();
    console.log("===>  received [200] json: " +obj);
  }  else if (status === 404) {
    console.log("===>  returned [400] ... returning null " );
  }
}, (e) => {
  console.log("===> AWS Error occurred " + JSON.stringify(e));
});
```

The server will return a 404 with a application/json response "Product 2420846325 not found" . I verified this in Postman and in a browser.

However, I don't see any of my  messages in the console...the closest I see is this:

```
Task <88A2709F-3CAD-4671-9D9F-67A95A177AC4>.<2> sent request, body N 0
Task <88A2709F-3CAD-4671-9D9F-67A95A177AC4>.<2> received response, status 404 content K
Task <88A2709F-3CAD-4671-9D9F-67A95A177AC4>.<2> done using Connection 2
Task <88A2709F-3CAD-4671-9D9F-67A95A177AC4>.<2> response ended
Task <88A2709F-3CAD-4671-9D9F-67A95A177AC4>.<2> summary for task success {transaction_duration_ms=2125, response_status=404, connection=2, protocol="h2", domain_lookup_duration_ms=3, connect_duration_ms=96, secure_connection_duration_ms=74, request_start_ms=106, request_duration_ms=0, response_start_ms=2123, response_duration_ms=2, request_bytes=195, response_bytes=370, cache_hit=1}
```

How should I be handling these non-200 responses so I can message back to my users?

Answer (score 0):

Newbie mistake, so maybe this can help someone else.

The problem is this line:

```
console.log("===> received response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
```

'**response**' is an httpResponse object, so to get it to work I changed to this:

```
console.log("===> received response: " + response.content.toString());
```

Because this was throwing an error, the logging messages were never picked up.